# Blender 2.83, Cycles, can't get pointiness to work

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

Guys I'm in a pickle here - regular scene, cube, uv unwrapped, cycles renderer selected and yet for a love of me I am unable to get pointiness to work.

[image: 8]

Comment: Top left view - is a rendered image, looks exactly the same in rendered view.

Comment: pointiness wont work on just a cube. there is no curvature for the node to work with.

Comment: Oh damn @Timaroberts you are right, what I missed is tad of geometry more. Post it as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: working on it, just a bit :)

Comment: By the way you don't need to UV unwrap your geometry to use the pointiness attribute

Comment: @Gorgious yea I figured out I'll just start trying all the stuff that came to my mind as I could not replicate the pointiness which I know I used long ago lol

Comment: And it doesn't work in Eevee, if you're ever wondering :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, on a cube with no curvature,or any type of bevel, you will see no result from  the pointiness output of the geometry node.

[Pointiness](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/geometry.html#geometry-node) as defined in the manual:

> An approximation of the curvature of the mesh per vertex. Lighter values indicate convex angles, darker values indicate concave angles. It allows you to do effects like dirt maps and wear-off effects.

You can see this clearly in the following example:

All objects have the same basic node setup including the default cube on the left.

[image]
<sup>*Click to enlarge*</sup>

The node seteup used:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What will help is having some decent subdivisions. Use Cycles, and use *Rendered Shading* mode.

This cost me over half a day to figure these out. They are often not mentioned in tutorials.